# Get online-only (On-Demand Files) files thumbnail from OneDrive sync folder

Tags: swift, onedrive

I am coding for a file manager app (like Finder.app) with swift, everything is OK until I open and browse the OneDrive sync folder.

I use `QLThumbnailGenerator` to get files thumbnail, here is my code:

```
func getThumbnail(filename: String) {
    let types = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request.RepresentationTypes.icon
    let req = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(
        fileAt: URL(fileURLWithPath: filename),
        size: CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 60.0),
        scale: NSScreen.main!.backingScaleFactor,
        representationTypes: types)
    
    QLThumbnailGenerator.shared.generateRepresentations(for: req) { (thumbnail, type, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            img = thumbnail?.nsImage
        }
    }
}
```

I found that `let types = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request.RepresentationTypes.icon` will trigger to download files, so I replace it to `let types = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request.RepresentationTypes.thumbnail`. Now, files will not be triggered to download, and I can not take the thumbnail either.

My question is: Is there a way to takes the thumbnail of online-only files?

Thank you!